# BadMethodCallException Method App\Http\Controllers\SiteController::index@index does not exist

Tags: php, laravel

I can not find the error:

My Controller:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class SiteController extends Controller{
    public function index(){
        return 'Home page do site';
    }
}
```

My Route:

Comment: You didn't add your routes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have not defined the route. we define route "web.php" of our laravel file.

```
 Route::get('/index', 'SiteController@index')->name('home');
```

this migght work for you.